# Python Ask.fm IP of Anonymous Questions

Tags: python, ip

I got much anonymous questions that attack my friendship.

Is there a way to get the IP-Adresss of these Questions with a Python script?

I have little more than normal Python knowledge, so you mustn't show me complete Code, just 1-5 lines or just explain something.

I hope you'll help me!

Comment: or finding a ip/user with the question ID : 1079XXXX91XXXX ... is this easier?

Answer (score 2):

If the IPs are not logged by ask.fm, there is not much you can do about it. And if it's logged, you probably don't need any script to extract it, as it should be presented somewhere along with the questions or separately in some list.

Comment: They might have, but at least in German jurisdiction, they wouldn't even be allowed to give you the IP.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Michael's answer, even if you might be able to get the IP you won't be able to do much. Most of people also use dynamic IP addresses.
You may want to contact ask.fm to get more informations, it's very hard they will give you them though.

Comment: Ok. Can you help me please to get the ip? i need the ip of the user who asked the  question.

Comment: Or can i get the ip when i have still the ip from the person i think she was?

Comment: Do you **really** know what an IP address **is**?